# What does "No Kami-sama himself" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw this in a novel "We are people that believe in Kami-sama and no Kami-sama himself" and I have no idea what "no Kami-sama himself" means.

> Lumachina shook her head left and right.
>
> 「Even if it’s possible for Kami-sama, it is impossible for people to do. We are people that believe in Kami-sama and no Kami-sama himself.」
>
> 「Hohou? So you are sermoning me……These High Chief Priests or whatever are quite remarkable, aren’t they. If you are that remarkable, let’s test out if you truly have God’s divine protection!」
>
> Lamnites readied her shouldered Magi Gun.
>
> She turned it towards Lumachina.
>
> — *Isekai Maou To Shoukan Shoujo Dorei Majutsu* Volume 4 Chapter 3 Part 9 via [Patreon](https://www.patreon.com/posts/volume-4-chapter-14251029)

Comment: Is this Japanese transcription? Presumably there is a character named 'Kami-sama'. Maybe there's a typo and it's 'not Kami-sama himself'?

Comment: I rather think it should be "*know* Kami-sama himself."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passage means roughly that just because Kami-Sama can do something does not mean we can do it, because **we don't have all the qualities and powers that Kami-Sama has**.

This is the same structure as a famous political insult. In a 1988 US Vice-Presidential debate between Dan Quayle and Lloyd Bentson, Bentson famously cracked:

> Senator, I served with Jack Kennedy. I knew Jack Kennedy. Jack Kennedy was a friend of mine. [**Senator, you're no Jack Kennedy.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Senator,_you%27re_no_Jack_Kennedy&oldid=854856670)

As Wikipedia explains, this line and variations have since

> become a part of the political lexicon as a way to deflate politicians or other individuals perceived as thinking too highly of themselves.

Your example

> We are people that believe in Kami-sama and no Kami-sama himself.

is likewise intended to deflate the expectations of what the target of the speech believes "we" can do.

The first part of the sentence, *We are people that believe in Kami-sama*, equates to *I knew Jack Kennedy*, indicating that Kami-Sama has known qualities. The second part, *and [we're] no Kami-sama himself* equates to *you're no Jack Kennedy*, meaning that "we" don't have Kami-Sama's qualities and therefore cannot do the things that Kami-Sama can.

I don't know whether this is an intentional nod to the political quote, or an unconscious or coincidental echo, but either way it follows standard English usage without interpreting in a typo.

Comment: That's a nice analysis. I still find it hard to read that way, though. But I'm not sure why...

Comment: @JamesRandom I suspect the author is intentionally trying to make the speaker sound affected or primitive or something, leaving the sentences a bit clunky.

Comment: You might be right. At first I thought "sermoning me" was just bad writing, but it might be a deliberate attempt to convey someone speaking a second language.

Comment: @JamesRandom: "sermoning" etc. look like artefacts of a bad translation to me. The original Japanese text might not have had the same clunky feel.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a typo; I guess what they meant to say is:

> We are people that believe in Kami-sama and **not** Kami-sama himself

Kami or kami-sama (with honorific suffix) is a general term for a god (roughly) in Japanese. I am assuming they are using it in the singular, to mean a particular god (perhaps the Christian one). So it is the same as saying:

> We are people that believe in God and not God himself

i.e. "we" are not God. (Would "and not God ourselves" or "and not God ourself" be better, I wonder?)

If kami-sama were plural it would probably be better as:

> We are people that believe in Kami-sama and **not** Kami-sama ourselves

I think it is more likely to be "not", rather than "know" as Andrew suggests, because the first sentence contrasts what the kami can do with what the humans can do.